# How to Solve this "void is not an iterator interface type"

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have the following error :

> cannot be an iterator block because 'void' is not an iterator
> interface type

This is the code I'm using :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;



 public class Pipe001Exit: MonoBehaviour
 {
        public AudioSource PipeSound;
        public GameObject FadeScreen;
        public GameObject MainCam;
        public GameObject SecondCam;
        public GameObject PipeEntry;
        public GameObject MainPlayer;
    
        void OnTriggerEnter(Collider col)
        {
            PipeSound.Play();
            FadeScreen.SetActive(true);
            FadeScreen.GetComponent < Animator > ().enabled = true;
            
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.495f);
            FadeScreen.GetComponent < Animator > ().enabled = false;
            MainCam.SetActive(true);
            SecondCam.SetActive(false);
            MainPlayer.transform.position = new Vector3(25.5f, 1, 0.5f);
            PipeEntry.GetComponent < Animator > ().enabled = true;
            FadeScreen.GetComponent < Animator > ().enabled = true;
            
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.495f);
            FadeScreen.GetComponent < Animator > ().enabled = false;
            
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
            PipeEntry.GetComponent < Animator > ().enabled = false;
            FadeScreen.SetActive(false);
        }
 }
```

> where I am going wrong with this error " cannot be an iterator block because 'void' is not an iterator interface type"? I am new to Unity. to know how to fix this issue.

How to solve this issues?

[image: picture of unity]

Comment: When you use `yield return T`, your method needs to return an `IEnumerable<T>`. In your case, your method should return `IEnumerable<WaitForSeconds>`.

Comment: If method is `void`, it means that it returns nothing. Follow advice from @HansKilian, and change `void` to `IEnumerable<WaitForSeconds>`.

Comment: See the [example](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WaitForSeconds.html)

Comment: Answers below are true but actually `OnTriggerEnter` itself can be a Coroutine! Simply make it `IEnumerator OnTriggerEnter (...)` and you should be fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;



public class Pipe001Exit : MonoBehaviour
{
    public AudioSource PipeSound;
    public GameObject FadeScreen;
    public GameObject MainCam;
    public GameObject SecondCam;
    public GameObject PipeEntry;
    public GameObject MainPlayer;

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider col)
    {
        PipeSound.Play();
        StartCoroutine(Fade());
    }

    IEnumerator Fade()
    {
        FadeScreen.SetActive(true);
        FadeScreen.GetComponent<Animator>().enabled = true;

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.495f);
        FadeScreen.GetComponent<Animator>().enabled = false;
        MainCam.SetActive(true);
        SecondCam.SetActive(false);
        MainPlayer.transform.position = new Vector3(25.5f, 1, 0.5f);
        PipeEntry.GetComponent<Animator>().enabled = true;
        FadeScreen.GetComponent<Animator>().enabled = true;

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.495f);
        FadeScreen.GetComponent<Animator>().enabled = false;

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
        PipeEntry.GetComponent<Animator>().enabled = false;
        FadeScreen.SetActive(false);
    }
}
```

[Documentation link about Coroutines](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html)

Comment: It's better to not use "magic string` for method name on the `StartCoroutine`. It remains reference on your code.

Comment: @D.B true, fixed.

Answer (score 1):

As Hand Kilian and kosist told you on comment you cant use `yield return ...` on `void` method. You should use on `IEnumerable` method.

Here's an example of what you can do with your code :

```
public class Pipe001Exit : MonoBehaviour
{
    public AudioSource PipeSound;
    public GameObject FadeScreen;
    public GameObject MainCam;
    public GameObject SecondCam;
    public GameObject PipeEntry;
    public GameObject MainPlayer;

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider col)
    {
        StartCoroutine(Feedback());
    }

    public IEnumerator Feedback()
    {
        PipeSound.Play();
        FadeScreen.SetActive(true);
        FadeScreen.GetComponent<Animator>().enabled = true;

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.495f);
        FadeScreen.GetComponent<Animator>().enabled = false;
        MainCam.SetActive(true);
        SecondCam.SetActive(false);
        MainPlayer.transform.position = new Vector3(25.5f, 1, 0.5f);
        PipeEntry.GetComponent<Animator>().enabled = true;
        FadeScreen.GetComponent<Animator>().enabled = true;

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.495f);
        FadeScreen.GetComponent<Animator>().enabled = false;

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
        PipeEntry.GetComponent<Animator>().enabled = false;
        FadeScreen.SetActive(false);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The other answers and comments already pointed it out: You can't use `yield` in a `void` method, only in an `IEnumerator`.

**However, actually [`OnTriggerEnter`](https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.1/Documentation/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnTriggerEnter.html) itself can be  such a [Coroutine](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html)** and I suspect a little this is where the confusion came from.

You can simply make it

```
IEnumerator OnTriggerEnter (Collider col)
{
    ...
}
```

and you should be fine. In this case Unity automatically doesn't call this like a normal `void` method but starts it as a Coroutine.

---

Personally I would also recommend you make sure that there is always only one routine running and block other `OnTriggerEnter` routines until the current one finished:

```
private bool _alreadyCollided;

IEnumerator OnTriggerEnter (Collider col)
{
    if(_alreadyCollided) yield break;

    _alreadyCollided = true;

    ...

    _alreadyCollided = false;
}
```